# Closed form of integration

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I've been trying to find out the closed form result of that integration in order to get a closed form CDF. Can anyone help me on that? 
Some asymptotic simplification can also be considered.

\begin{equation}
 F_{W}(\rho)=\int_{w=0}^{w=\rho}\int_{x=0}^{x=1} x^{(\frac{M+1}{2})}(1-x)^{(\frac{M-4}{2})}w^{(\frac{M-2}{2})} \{ {(x+wc)}^{-M}+ {(w+cx)}^{-M}\}dxdw
\end{equation}

Comment: Is there some special meaning to the $\{ \dots \}$?

Comment: no, any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have experience with complicated integrals. Have you investigated Laplace transforms?

Comment: Hi @ishmamzabir . How are the constants $M$ and $c$ have to be?  positive?

Comment: yes, they both are positive.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: @ishmamzabir May also assume $0<\rho$ and $2<M$? If so, then I can at least give you an answer in terms of hypergeometric functions...

Comment: this is a fair assumption , we can assume that, then, can you suggest anything?